# FTP GET terminal syntax

Tags: ftp

How do I FTP GET this file from a Unix terminal?

ftp://ftp.imagemagick.org/pub/ImageMagick/ImageMagick.tar.gz

My attempts:

```
/home# ftp
-bash: ftp: command not found

/home# sftp ftp.imagemagick.org/pub/ImageMagick/ImageMagick.tar.gz
ssh: Could not resolve hostname 
    ftp.imagemagick.org/pub/ImageMagick/ImageMagick.tar.gz:
    Name or service not known

/home# sftp ftp.imagemagick.org
root@ftp.imagemagick.org's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your system has [`wget`](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/), using this would most definitely be the easiest choice. Just do:

```
wget ftp://ftp.imagemagick.org/pub/ImageMagick/ImageMagick.tar.gz
```